# Difference between self.object and _object

Tags: objective-c

In Objective-C, what is the difference between calling an object with the underscore (calling instance variable) or calling it with the `self` keyword? As an example, I setup a simple `.h` and `.m` file called `Methods` that inherits from `NSObject.h`.

**Contents of `Methods.h`**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Methods : NSObject

@property int firstNumber;
@property int secondNumber;

@end
```

**Contents of `Methods.m`**

```
#import "Methods.h"

@implementation Methods

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _firstNumber = 33;
        self.secondNumber = 67;

        NSLog(@"The value of _firstNumber is: %i", _firstNumber);
        NSLog(@"The value of self.secondNumber is: %i", self.secondNumber);
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

This is the result in the command line when this code is executed:

```
2014-07-07 20:22:08.551 CommandLine[2771:39622] The value of _firstNumber is: 33
2014-07-07 20:22:08.552 CommandLine[2771:39622] The value of self.secondNumber is: 67
```

This is the expected result, as the values have the numeric value that they were set to, and I've developed using both the underscore and the `self` keyword to call and set objects,  so what makes one better than another? Or is it a case of personal preference and custom?

Comment: Also, see that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086736/why-would-you-use-an-ivar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned one is an instance variable and the other is a property. In the earlier days of Objective-C there were different scenarios in which one would be better. Now they both act very similar and it is mainly a preference choice. There are arguments over which one is better but it really shouldn't matter which one you're using.

Comment: However Xcode suggests _ form in its tooltips.

Comment: @SzymonFortuna that's just apple not changing from their old ways. Don't worry about it

Comment: it's just that they offer me one button fix when changing from variable in a method to the property this way