# Performance: dot syntax VS ivar

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance

```
@interface Person : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, assign) CGFloat salary;
@end

@implementation Person
- (void)addSalary:(CGFloat)s
{
    _salary += s; **//method 1**
    self.salary += s; **//method 2**
}
@end
```

I wonder which is more efficient between method 1 and 2?
Would the compiler do some optimisation work to make them have the same performance?

Comment: Read all the points here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142177/difference-between-self-ivar-and-ivar?rq=1

Comment: That question is not about the performance between self.ivar and ivar. Somebody advise to use self.ivar, it makes sense in non ARC environment. If ARC adopted, no memory leak will be brought in with ivar even if it is an id instance. So I want to know whether the performance is the same or not?
"Accessors are highly optimized in Objective-C and provide important features for maintainability and flexibility. As a general rule, you should refer to all properties, even your own, using their accessors." from <<iOS 5 programming pushing the limits>> .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, using `_salary` will be faster than `self.salary` and I doubt that the compiler can do (in the general case) any optimization here either simply because there is no guarantee that a subclass would not implement `-salary` or `setSalary:` itself. Then there is all the aspects of key-value notifications. Setting `self.salary` will trigger key value observers while using the ivar wont. My take is that unless you are in a very large and tight loop, it won't make a noticable difference in your app and using `self.salary` is more robust in that it allows for the possibility of subclasses. I could also add that the objective-c runtime is very efficient in it's dispatch of methods.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 will be as fast or faster than method 2. But you should still use method 2 for other reasons. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16012387/1597531